# How to validate a JSON Request object in laravel validation?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

How will I validate the current entries from here , this is the json response inside the Chrome Devtools after submitting the form thru axios ?

[image: JSON Response]

And this is in my UpdateProfileRequest.php

```
    public function rules()
    {
     return [
        'username'         => 'required|unique:users|min:3',
       'password'    =>      'required|min:8|confirmed',
       'confirm_password'        => 'required|',
       'current_password'       => 'required|u',
       'country_id'      => 'required|integer',
       'display_name'     => 'required|min:5',
       'email'    => 'required|unique:users,email_address',
       'phone_number' => 'required|alpha_num',
       'image' => 'mimes:jpg,png,gif'
     ];
```

This is the whole response from the request

[image: In the App\Http\Requests\UpdateProfileRequest]

This is inside my UpdateProfile.vue

```html
<div>
        <div v-if="user != null">
            <form class="bg-white m-auto h-full p-4 w-full" id="setup-billing-form" @submit.prevent="submitProfile()" method="POST">
                <div class="flex inline-block">
                    <div id="input-group" class="w-3/5">    
                        <label for="name" class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-black-v2 text-xs font-bold mb-2">Username
                        </label>
                        <input v-model="form.username" type="text" class="hover:bg-grey-lightest bg-grey-lighter w-full mb-2 p-2 leading-normal" id="pin" name="pin" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Your Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div id="input-group" class="ml-2 w-3/5">   
                        <label for="name" class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-black-v2 text-xs font-bold mb-2">Email
                        </label>
```

this is is inside my axios request

```
submitProfile(){
        let data = new FormData();
        axios.put(this.endpoint, { 
            form : this.form , 
            image : this.image
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);             
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Now, I want to ask if how do I validate those requests inside my UpdateProfileRequest, should I add the `form.` to each of those requests ?

Comment: Can u post your view's code?

Comment: What view do you mean @TsaiKoga

Comment: I means the form.

Comment: Please read the description above, I already gave you the request form

Comment: plz post your axios code.

Comment: You can do it by firstly decode the json to array and then add the form request to laravel request by merge function. i give a example below 

$request = $request->merge(json_decode($request->form, true));
Add this code in your controller.
Then pass  request to laravel rules, I hope it works for me.

Comment: @TheBAST It seems that you new a `formdata` without using it, so what is your `content-type`

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't used completely the FormData instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two Methods:

#### 1. just use form.username to validate

```php
$rule = [
        'form.username'         => 'required|unique:users|min:3',
       'form.password'    =>      'required|min:8|confirmed',
       'form.confirm_password'        => 'required|',
       'form.current_password'       => 'required|u',
       'form.country_id'      => 'required|integer',
       'form.display_name'     => 'required|min:5',
       'form.email'    => 'required|unique:users,email_address',
       'form.phone_number' => 'required|alpha_num',
       'image' => 'mimes:jpg,png,gif'
     ];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
}
```

#### 2. Flatten the object to request:

It seems that you new a `formdata` without using it.

And pass the data with keys `form` and `image`.

You need to flatten your object before put it:

```js
submitProfile(){
        // if you use formdata
        // let form = new FormData(this.form);
        // let form = form.append('image', this.image);
        let form = Object.assign({}, this.form);  // clone this.form
        form['image'] = this.image;

        axios.put(this.endpoint, form).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);             
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

This request that you can directly validate by
`'username', 'password', ...` without prefix `form`.

and if you want to insert the datas, you can just use `$request->except('image')`.

Comment: Is it advisable to use formdata ??

Comment: Because I'm not using formdata inside it

Comment: @TheBAST ok, I have changed it to object.

Comment: Please show me a way on how yo handle that in your controller

Comment: `axios.put(this.endpoint, { 
    form : this.form , 
    image : this.image
   }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);    
   }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
   });` 
My form looks like this 
`form : { 
    username : this.user.username, 
    email : this.user.email, 
    id : this.user.id, 
    current_password : "",
    password : "", 
    confirm_password : "", 
    display_name : this.user.display_name,
    phone_number : this.user.phone_number,
    country_id : this.user.country_id
    // uploadUrl : urls.update_profiles_endpoint,
   }`

Comment: @TheBAST why you want to put those attributes into multiple level object? I think you need to flatten that object.

Comment: so that I can group them up, and I don't have to pass a lot of params inside my axios instance

Comment: @TheBAST Use the flatten one, if you want to insert the datas, you just need to use `$request->except('image')` and get the form. However, if you group them, you still need to remove the prefix `form.` and insert the datas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203496/discussion-between-thebast-and-tsaikoga).

Comment: Well, I can insert the data through `request()->input('form.username')` something  like that, but I can't validate the data, I need something that can validate the data

Comment: @TheBAST if you still want to pass that object, you can validate `form.username`, I have updated my answer.

Comment: this is already answered man thanks a lot, found your answer to be helpful but I used mine it's far simpler and easy but same as you it uses validator

Comment: @TheBAST glad you made it.